# Fingerprint browser and drive visitors

Tags: browser, fingerprint

Excuse me in advance, if you have submitted the application or the problem is not divided Please help solve this problem Or my topic is moved to the appropriate section I have an Arabic chat site as a wonder chat Chat is a script

During my search for the most powerful methods of banning annoying visitors within the chat and found these files bearing the name of the browser fingerprint Link to the Fingerprint file to make a distinctive fingerprint of the browser. 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/li...rprint2.min.js

Working file idea:

The basic idea of ​​the file is to make a distinctive imprint for the browser to distinguish members on the site even if the member changed his name and change his IP, and also the file can fetch a lot of information through the browser of the member such as the version of the browser and state and city and the private Internet company used by the member. The only problem we have now is how to use the file to bring the fingerprint of the browser to the member and fetch the basic data from the browser such as the state, city and its Internet company, to store this data on the datapize and use it to protect the site and chat from spam and annoying members.

Thank you for your presence.

Site Link:
 https://www.3a-chat.com/chat

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the library URL in your question does not work, but I would recommend using [this existing solution](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) and extending it a bit. For example you may add:

- pixel ratio `window.devicePixelRatio || 1`
- languages `(navigator.languages || []).join(',')`
- math precision `${((Math.exp(10) + 1 / Math.exp(10)) / 2)}${Math.tan(-1e300)}`